# Using autocomplete with ActsAsTaggableOn

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to add autocomplete to a form where users enter topics as tags. The application I'm adding this feature to uses foundation (not bootstrap). The tagging bit works fine which I've implemented with the ActsAsTaggableOn gem.

I've followed a few posts on adding the autocomplete functionality, including http://deveede.logdown.com/posts/211450-acts-astaggable-as-rails4-autocomplete but I've not had any joy.

I get an error message,

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui' in application.css
```

If I remove the require in the css file, I get a similar message for application.js. Having looked at a bunch of posts, its not clear which gems I should be using and if indeed this is an approach that will work. I appreciate any suggestions.

Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'rails4-autocomplete'
```

routes.rb

```
resource :users do
  get :autocomplete_topic_name, on: :collection
end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery_ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

application.css

```
*= require jquery-ui
```

user.rb

```
acts_as_taggable_on :topics
```

users_controller.rb

```
autocomplete :topic, :name, class_name: 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag'
```

form.html.haml

```
= f.input :topic_list, label: "Topics, enter as a comma separated list", url: autocomplete_topic_name_users_path, as: :autocomplete, input_html: {'data-delimiter' => ','}
```